# Map a drive in Windows using different credentials

Tags: windows, networking, mount, network-shares, login

I have 2 networked computers C1 and C2 using same login credentials.
Because they are using same credentials, I can access shared folders on C1 from C2 without entering credentials.
The problem is I want to access a shared folder on C1 from C2 using a different account that is on C1.
If I try to Map the drive with using 'Connect using different credentials', I get the following error:

> "The network folder specified is currently mapped using a different
>   user name and password. To connect using a different user name and
>   password, first disconnect any existing mappings to this network
>   share."

The problem is **I haven't done ANY mapping.**
All there is in 'This PC' is my primary SSD and thats it.
Since I can access the folders on C1 shared under same credentials as on C2, windows is automatically mapping them I suppose!
Please advice a solution.
P.S. I DO NOT need any access to C1 folders with same credentials as C2 which windows is allowing atm.
EDIT: I am aware that one solution can be to use different credentials on both computers but currently that isn't a viable solution.

Comment: Try mapping the drive with the different credential with the IP address rather than the machine DNS name or vice versa and see if that makes any difference. Just a quick idea i.e. `\\192.168.1.X\\sharename` or `\\machinename\sharename`

Comment: I see "New connections will be remembered. There are no entries in the list."

Comment: Try running `NET USE * /DELETE /Y` from a command line and then try to map again and see if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Not really what I wanted but changing credentials of C1 from that of C2 worked.

Answer (score 0):

There's an app on the Windows store which can do this. It's called "Advanced Share Mapper."

I know it works because I wrote it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).